# Angular 1, Angular Dart or Angular 2.0 alpa. is Angular 2.0 production ready yet?

Tags: angularjs

With Angular 2.0  being an alpha and a production release coming up soon, would you start a new project in 1.0, dart or 2.0 today?

Is Angular 2.0 production ready yet?

Comment: this is technically an opinion based question, but the official canonical opinion is "Angular 2 is currently in Alpha Preview. We recommend using Angular 1.X for production applications."  https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/

Comment: I would also consider your timeline, will this application be released in the next 6 months or is it a large enterprise app that might be in development for the next year(s)?

Comment: Brad Green (@bradlygreen, Google Angular Product Manager) Answered on twitter: Angular 1, for certain.  I'd wait at least until we label it "beta" before seriously considering.

Comment: RIP angular 1.x, you will forget everything you learned..

Comment: Seems Angular 2 is coming something close to a stable release! Checkout angular.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 1.x is the best option to go with and if you follow the upgrade cycle you will be able to migrate to Angular 2 eventually (that's the idea anyway).

"The theme of 1.5 will be supporting integration with Angular 2." - http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/announcements-from-ng-conf-were.html

My expectation is that 2.0 is still in a state of flux to a degree.

I'm not sure I would look at Dart unless you have a specific market. Angular 1.x covers the most bases and has plenty of resources to help you out should you get stuck or need more information.

Answer (score 1):

** This is OLD advice now **

I would stick with 1.x for now.

But, that's based on my needs and my customers needs.

Angular 2 targets evergreen browsers and for the enterprise we will still have the 'old browser' issue.

Angular 1 will be around for sometime.

If you are doing a green field dev and your go live lands when 2.0 lands and you want to target evergreen browsers then I would go 2

Comment: thx drake, for now Angular 1 seems the better choice.

Comment: Just removed my quote as blog that I referenced was older than I thought